# How to update chart when state changes in vue?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuex, mixins

I've mapped chartData to a state property using vuex. What I'd like to do is update the chart when a dataset is updated. I have heard that it can be done with mixins or watchers but I don't know how to implement it. I understand that mixins creates a watcher but I don't know how it is used within vuex.

Chartline.vue:

```
<script>
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'ChartLine',
  extends: Line,
    computed:{
      ...mapState(['charData','options'])
    },
    methods:{
      regraph: function(){
        this.renderChart(this.charData,this.options);
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.regraph();
    },
    watch: {
    }
}
</script>
```

Pension.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id='pension' class="navbarPar">
    <ChartLine/> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChartLine from '../components/ChartLine.vue';
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
//import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  name: 'Pension',
  components: {
    ChartLine,
  },
  data(){
    return{
      form: {
        ...
      },
      var:{
        ...
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {

    calculate: function(indice){
      ...
      //modify data of mapState
      //after here, I want to rerender chart
      }
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapState(['charData','options']),

  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a watcher like this should be enough:

```
<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "ChartLine",
  extends: Line,
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["chartData", "options"])
  },
  methods: {
    regraph() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.regraph();
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      handler: this.regraph,
      deep: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Also having the explicit vuex state map inside the ChartLine component seems a bit wasteful - passing the vuex data through props would render the component more generic:

```
<template>
  <div id='pension' class="navbarPar">
    <ChartLine :options="options" :chart-data="chartData"/> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>...
```

Chartline.vue:

```
<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  name: "ChartLine",
  extends: Line,
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    },
    chartData: {
      type: Object /*is it?*/,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  methods: {
    regraph() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.regraph();
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      handler: this.regraph,
      deep: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue-chartjs, the library has its own way to handle reactive data in charts:

```
// ChartLine.js
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'], // passed from the parent
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin (pass it as any prop with :chart-data="data").
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

Now the Pension.vue file

```
// Pension.vue
<template>
  <div id='pension' class="navbarPar">
    <ChartLine :chart-data="charData" :options="options" /> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChartLine from '../components/ChartLine';
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'Pension',
    components: {
      ChartLine,
    },
    data(){
      return{
        form: {
          ...
        },
        var:{
          ...
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      calculate: function(indice){
      ...
      //modify data of mapState
      //after here, I want to rerender chart
      }
    },
    computed:{
      ...mapState(['charData','options']),
    },
  }
</script>
```

You can read more about it here: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts,
there are some caveats