# vue-chartJs, Unable to update the chart

Tags: vue.js, charts, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

I am using Vue-Chartjs to create a simple Line chart, I'm filling the chart with data via a get request to an API

however I want to generate new values randomly when I click on a button, & pass the values as a prop to `chart-line` component.
I've tried using `reactiveProp` & I also tried using a watcher for `chartData` prop, but I'm always getting this error

```
client.js?06a0:83 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

### Dashboard Component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Dashboard Page</h1>

    <v-alert v-if="errorDetected"
      class="mt-4"
      dense
      outlined
      type="error"
    >
      There was an error while getting the chart data
    </v-alert>

    <v-btn @click="generateNewData()">Generate new data</v-btn>

    <div class="loader-container">
      <img v-if="!loaded" class="chart-loader mt-3" src="../static/loader-dotted.gif" alt="">
    </div>

    <ChartLine v-if="loaded" :chartData="values" :bind="true" />
  </div>  
</template>

<script>
import ChartLine from '../components/chart-line'
export default {
  middleware: 'session',
  components: {
    ChartLine
  },
  data() {
    return {
      values: [],
      customValues: [],
      loaded: false,
      errorDetected: false
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Dashboard page',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'simple dashboard SPA'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.requestData()
  },
  methods: {
    requestData() {
      this.loaded = false
        this.$axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5eda474f330000fefc79eab4?mocky-delay=2000ms').then(response => {
        console.log("requestData -> response", response)
        this.values = response.data.data.value
        this.loaded = true
      }).catch(error => {
        this.loaded = true
        this.errorDetected = true
      })
    },
    generateNewData() {
      this.values = [];
      for(let i=0; i<7; i++)
        this.values.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1))
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.loader-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chart-loader {
  width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

### ChartLine Component

```
<script>
  //Importing Line class from the vue-chartjs wrapper
  import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
  const { reactiveProp } = mixins


  //Exporting this so it can be used in other components
  export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    props: ['chartData'],
    data () {
      return {
        datacollection: {
          //Data to be represented on x-axis
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data 1",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              borderColor: "rgba(1, 116, 188, 0.50)",
              pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(171, 71, 188, 1)",
              //Data to be represented on y-axis
              data: this.chartData
            }
          ],
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
        //Chart.js options that controls the appearance of the chart
      }
    },
    watch: {
      chartData() {
        this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options)
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      //renderChart function renders the chart with the datacollection and options object.
      this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

### UPDATE

I've managed to solve the issue of updating the chart
I removed the `dataCollection` from the `chart-line` component & added it in the `dashboard` component, I've also used the `requestData()` method in the `created()` hook to make a get request to the API, then on a button click I generate a new values and pass it as a prop

### Update Code

#### Dashboard Component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Dashboard Page</h1>

    <v-alert v-if="errorDetected"
      class="mt-4"
      dense
      outlined
      type="error"
    >
      There was an error while getting the chart data
    </v-alert>

    <v-btn class="primary" @click="generateNewData()">Generate New Data</v-btn>

    <div class="loader-container">
      <img v-if="!loaded" class="chart-loader mt-3" src="../static/loader-dotted.gif" alt="">
    </div>

    <ChartLine v-if="loaded" :chart-data="dataCollection" />
  </div>  
</template>

<script>
import ChartLine from '../components/chart-line'
export default {
  middleware: 'session',
  components: {
    ChartLine
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dataCollection: null,
      values: [],
      customValues: [],
      loaded: false,
      errorDetected: false
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Dashboard page',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'simple dashboard SPA'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  created() {
    // this.loaded = false
    // this.fillData()
    // this.loaded = true
    this.requestData()
  },
  methods: {
    requestData() {
      this.loaded = false
        this.$axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5eda474f330000fefc79eab4?mocky-delay=2000ms').then(response => {
        this.values = response.data.data.value
        this.loaded = true
        this.fillData()
      }).catch(error => {
        this.loaded = true
        this.errorDetected = true
      })
    },

    fillData () {
      this.dataCollection = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Data 1",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              borderColor: "rgba(1, 116, 188, 0.50)",
              pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(171, 71, 188, 1)",
              data: this.values
            }
          ]
        }
      },

    generateNewData() {
      this.values = []
      this.loaded = false
      setTimeout(function(){},2000)
      for(let i=0; i<7; i++) {
          this.values.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5)
      }
      this.fillData()
      this.loaded = true
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style>
.loader-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chart-loader {
  width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

#### Chart-Line Component

```
<script>
  //Importing Line class from the vue-chartjs wrapper
  import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

  //Exporting this so it can be used in other components
  export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
    // props:['chartData'],
    data () {
      return {
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
        //Chart.js options that controls the appearance of the chart
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      //renderChart function renders the chart with the datacollection and options object.
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

- however there's still one thing I can't figure out, which is the loading state, when clicking on the button to generate new data
- when I first open the dashboard page, the loading state works, but when I click on the button, loading state doesn't work

any Idea why??????

Comment: I dont really know off the bat, but your chart template v-if is waiting for the loaded flag to be true, generateNewData() method isn't setting a true value - not saying this is the problem. For now if you set the v-if="values" instead of loaded, and see if it makes a difference. Also could you recreate this issue in a codepen so others can debug it?

Comment: Check this answer, it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200107/how-to-update-chart-when-state-changes-in-vue/62203075#62203075, using reactiveProp mixin, you don't have to declare the charData property in your component, the mixin does it for you.